# Transforming dataframe to contain counts of values

Tags: r

Have created a dataframe that contains ids and stringvalues :

```
mycols <- c('id','2')
ids <- c(1,1,2,3)
stringvalues <- c('a','a','b','c')
mydf <- data.frame(ids , stringvalues)
```

mydf contains :

```
  ids stringvalues
1   1            a
2   1            a
3   2            b
4   3            c
```

I'm attempting to produce a new dataframe that contains the id and 
corresponding counts for each string :

```
id, a , b , c
1 , 2 , 0 , 0
2 , 0 , 1 , 0
3 , 0 , 0 , 1
```

I'm trying to create multiple summarise implementations :

```
g1 <- group_by(mydf , ids)  
s1 <- summarise(g1 , a = count('a')) 
s2 <- summarise(g1 , b = count('b')) 
s3 <- summarise(g1 , c = count('c'))
```

But returns error : `Evaluation error: no applicable method for 'groups' applied to an object of class "character".`

How to create new columns that count number of string entries in the column ?

Comment: Does `table(mydf)` do the job?

Comment: `dcast()` will do. I am sure there are similar questions on SO.

Comment: @blue-sky - Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

Does doing a `dplyr::count` followed by `tidyr::spread` work for you? (I'm only posting this as you mentioned you were wanting to create a dataframe of this sort - otherwise it's much simpler to use `table(mydf)` as the other comments/answers suggest.)

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydf %>% count(ids, stringvalues) %>% spread(stringvalues, n, fill = 0)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>     ids     a     b     c
#> * <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2     0     0
#> 2     2     0     1     0
#> 3     3     0     0     1
```

Comment: This is a good dplyr solution +1. For future cases, you can also cbind a table output to convert it to a data frame (see other answer for how).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base-R solution:

```
data.frame(cbind(table(mydf)))
```

Output option 1 (row # = ID):

```
  a b c
1 2 0 0
2 0 1 0
3 0 0 1
```

Output option 2 (with ID as column):

```
data.frame(cbind(id=unique(mydf$ids),table(mydf)))

  id a b c
1  1 2 0 0
2  2 0 1 0
3  3 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count` directly. First,

```
count(mydf, ids,stringvalues)
```

gives

```
 # A tibble: 3 x 3
 ids stringvalues     n
 <dbl>       <fctr> <int>
1     1            a     2
2     2            b     1
3     3            c     1
```

then reshape,

```
count(mydf, ids,stringvalues) %>% tidyr::spread(stringvalues, n)
```

gives

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
    ids     a     b     c
* <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     2    NA    NA
2     2    NA     1    NA
3     3    NA    NA     1
```

then replace the NAs with something like `res[is.na(res)] <- 0`, where `res` is the object constructed above.